# Perform validation on hidden fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have the view below:

```
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompanyPostCode)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompanyPostCode)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompanyCity)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompanyCity)

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CompanyCityID)
```

All attributes are marked as **[Required]** in my view model. Then problem is that my CompanyCityID (marked as Required) is hidden and thus no validation is done in the view. If I show this attribute in my view the validation is done.

[image]

My question: is it possible to perform a validation on a hidden field? A workaround exist?

It may seems a little strange to validate a hidden field. The reason is that this field is filled from jQuery based on special rules. If it is not filled, I know something is not valid on the view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The possible reason can be that there is `ignore: ':hidden'` line in `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` file.

After 1.9.0 version it is a default behaviour. You can fix that manually by adding

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: [] });
```

As you can see [here](http://bassistance.de/2011/10/07/release-validation-plugin-1-9-0/)

> Another change should make the setup of forms with hidden elements
>   easier, these are now ignored by default (*option “ignore” has
>   “:hidden” now as default*). In theory, this could break an existing
>   setup. In the unlikely case that it actually does, **you can fix it by
>   setting the ignore-option to “[]” (square brackets without the
>   quotes).**

Comment: I really hate being that guy that corrects people but the ignore setting isn't set by jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js.  Also, be aware of how setDefaults works before using it.  If you set defaults after you've already wired up the validation for the form then you're too late with this call.  Please see my write up for a more in-depth explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466643/jquery-validate-enable-validation-for-hidden-fields/14574974#14574974

Comment: @JustinMichaels, maybe something has changed since I wrote this answer. At that time I checked jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js and ignore setting was there.

Comment: Excellent answer, I was looking for this for like 3 hours...  "Thank YOU, Chuck Norris!" (like from the movie Dodgeball with Vince Vaughn)

Comment: Hey wait you're too young to be Chuck Norris!

Comment: Chuck Norris doesn't know what is age... He lives forever.

Comment: Keep in mind that you **don't** put `$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: [] });` in a `$(document).ready` as this will be too late. If you can't do so, use: `$('form').validate().settings.ignore = []`

Comment: This worked for me `$('form').validate().settings.ignore = ":hidden:not(#SelectedReports)";` while `$('form').validate({ ignore: ":hidden:not(#SelectedReports)"});` did not. Just a tip for anyone else stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just comment out this line in the jquery.validate.js file.
ignore: ":hidden"

Comment: duplicate answer to Chuck Norris

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use javascript, in your Controller, and in your action of the related view, you can add a model error before validating your model. Example:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Fix(YourModel mdl)
    {

    if (mdl.CompanyCityID==0)
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your error message!");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {


       //
       //Some code
       //

        return View("YourView", yourlist);
    }

    return View(mdl);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always put `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CompanyCityID)` inside a hidden div and change it to `EditorFor()`.

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}​
```

**View**

```
<div class="hidden">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CompanyCityID)
</div
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. I think it can still tell that it's hidden, even if it's a parent that's hidden.