# Client Side validation for a particular hidden field in Asp.net-MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using data annotation for validation and also using unobtrusive.js for client side validation.

I have several hidden fields that are not validated (and I don't need) by default as per the default setting of jquery.validate.js (ignore: ":hidden").

In my case I just want to validate a particular hidden field and not the all as a result I can't override

```
                   ***ignore: ":hidden"*** to  ***ignore:[]***.
```

If it is changed then all hidden fields will be considered for validation which is not my requirement.

Have no idea how to enable validation for a particular hidden field.

```
 [ValidDate(ErrorMessage = "This is not a valid date.Please enter date in dd/mm/yyyy format.")]
 public string HiddenSelectedDob { get; set; }
```

Where `ValidDate` is a custom attribute.

Here I am taking input from the user for the day , month and year from three different dropdowns and for the change event of each drop down the value of the `HiddenSelectedDob` will be set using jQuery.

Finally on submit this hidden filed should be validate.

I have given a class name to that hidden filed like..

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.HiddenSelectedDob, new { @class = "validateAlways" })
```

and override the default setting of jquery.validate.js like

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(.validateAlways)" });
```

but the result is same. The field is not validating.

Comment: If you have correctly validated the fields that make up the parts then is the hidden dob not then always valid?

Comment: Actually there needs a validation for the combination like 31/02/2016 is not a valid date but the individual fields like 31 , 02 and 2016 are valid.

Comment: You should tighten up the way you load the dropdowns, you should never allow invalid entries in a drop down list, that's the point of a drop down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the only way I see is to add a class to the hidden input that you wanna validate.

So you'll have to do this at the view level.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.HiddenSelectedDob, new{@class="validateAlways"})
```

Then, change the ignore rule of validate.js to

```
ignore: ':hidden:not('.validateAlways')'
```

Which means : ignore all hidden inputs, except if they have a `validateAlways` class.

Comment: Thanks !! but it is not working. Override like '$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(.validateAlways)" });'

Comment: The class name needs to be quoted - `$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ':hidden:not('.validateAlways')' });` (and then it will work fine). And you can also use an `id` - ':hidden:not('#HiddenSelectedDob')'`