# Validation Message For Range Attribute MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

The following Model has Required attributes for certain parameters:

```
   public class EModel
    {        
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Tel")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public float Long { get; set; }
        public float Lat{ get; set; }
    }
```

In my Views, I have Name, Phone, and 2 float Parameters: longitude and latitude that I keep in a hidden input, they are set by a map marker to be saved later.

I am validating the required parameters like the following:

```
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Name" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "danger" })
</div>
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Phone" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "danger" })
</div>
<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Long, new { @id = "Long"})
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Lat, new { @id = "Lat"})
</div>
<div>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</div>
```

I need to add a validation to the long and lat parameters, because I dont want the user to save without choosing a location first. so long and lat should not be lesser than 0.001, so I added the following attribute:

```
[Range(0.001, float.MaxValue)]
public float Long { get; set; }
[Range(0.001, float.MaxValue)]
public float Lat{ get; set; }
```

I want to validate on Submit click, the fact that **Long and Lat are both not 0.00**.

How can i do this? `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Long)` did not work.

Comment: Why do you want to validate a field that cannot be set by user input? By default client validation will not work for hidden fields. Server side validation should still work though

Comment: @ste-fu I edited to explain more. the float value is set by a map marker. I dont want to let the user save without choosing a location first

Comment: *I dont want to let the user save without choosing a location first*.. so you want to check if there is a value or not?  or check if long & lat are < .001?

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572749/mvc-how-to-enable-client-side-validation-on-hidden-fields?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid value of long and lat is by default 0.00. I want to see if it changed

Comment: Are you opposed to checking this via server-side?  You can check that server-side and return an error message.

Comment: If the location is on the Greenwich Meridian then the latitude will be zero. If the location is on the equator then the longitude will be zero. It seems failing on zero values makes a significant number of locations unavailable.

Comment: @Richard Think you got that the wrong way round, but you make a valid point. There are valid inputs that would have lat or long of 0 (albeit a bit unlikely to select on using a pin on a map)

Comment: @ste-fu The change of me getting them the right way round should be 50%, but in practice is about 5% :-( .

Comment: @Richard I want to put a condition where both should be different than 0 for that reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `$.validator` does not validate hidden inputs. You can override this behavior by adding the following script

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
    ignore: [] 
});
```

or if you want to validate just these 2 hidden inputs and ignore other hidden inputs, give these a class name (say `new { @class = "coordinates" }`) and use

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
    ignore: ':hidden:not('.coordinates')'
});
```

An alternative would be to generate the values as readonly textboxes which would also give extra feedback to the user

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Long, new { @readonly = "readonly"})
```

Note that is is not necessary to use `new { @id = "Long"})` - the `HtmlHelper` methods that generate form controls already adds an `id` attribute based on the name of the property.

However, your range validation does not really make sense since zero and negative values are valid for coordinates. If your wanting to ensure that the user has selected a location (and the values have been set via your script), then make the properties `nullable` and add a `RequiredAttribute`

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a location")]
public float? Long { get; set; } // nullable
```

Comment: That's a great answer thanks. But on document load now by default the marker in the map is set on 0,0. If i make it nullable the map will take coordinates of null and the marker won't be set. Which is an issue.

Comment: So your using the same property to set an initial value? (you did not show any of the script). You could always test for `null` and if so, set the initial lat/long to 0,0

Answer (score 0):

Given that Lat/Long can be negative as well as positive I would suggest populating a different field to indicate that a location has been selected:

```
public float Long { get; set; }
public float Lat{ get; set; }

[MinValue(1, "Please select a location")
public int LatLongCheck { get; set; }
```

Then in whatever code you use to set the Lat & Long, you can also set the value of LatLongCheck to 1 (or whatever).

Use whatever technique works for you in the link (as per L-Four's comment) [MVC : How to enable client side validation on hidden fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572749/mvc-how-to-enable-client-side-validation-on-hidden-fields) to enable the client side validation.

You could also take a look at [Foolproof Validation](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/) which has a `[NotEqualTo]` validation attribute which you could use instead of an alternative field. Finally you could consider displaying the Lat / Long values as `readonly` fields, which are validated by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the longitude and latitude input with CSS

```
<div style="visibility: hidden;">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Long, new { @id = "Long"})
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lat, new { @id = "Lat"})
</div>
<div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Long)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lat)
</div>
```

---

And set it as required in your model

```
public class EModel
{        
    [Required]
    [Range(0.001, float.MaxValue)]
    [Display(Name = "Long")]
    public string Long { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0.001, float.MaxValue)]
    [Display(Name = "Lat")]
    public string Lat { get; set; }

}
```