# Field hidden via CSS always validates to true

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation

I am using `MVC 5` and I have a strange problem with the built in validation:
On my page is a tab-control which shows and hides div's via their `display` style.
My model has some fields which are decorated with `[Required]`.

If I now leave such a field on tab #1 empty and switch to tab #2 and trigger the validation (e.g. try to submit the form) the field on tab #1 validates to `true` and if there are no other validation errors on tab #2 the form submits. If I switch back to tab #1 and trigger the validation again without any change otherwise the field correctly fails the validation.

I already tried removing the ignoring of hidden fields via:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: null });
```

But that did not help either.

I use [THIS](https://gist.github.com/remi/957732) hooks to do some custom task after the validation and there I see the validation is executed, but really returns the wrong result.

*Does someone have an idea how I can fix this?*

Comment: See both [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14506637/594235).

Comment: @Sparky: Thx - worked, BUT only when NOT inside `$(document).ready(function () { });`. I wonder why I did not find that question even if searching nearly exactly for their title...