# Validating @Html.HiddenFor() field value before posting the view model in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

This is my problem:

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC framework, I'm creating new records on a database with a "Create" view, that receives a Viewmodel in order to send the data from client to server.

I implemented some properties validations with **Data Annotations** in my ViewModel definition, such as **"Required", "Range", "DataType"**, most of my inputs are validated correctly before sending the request to server side, except one.

This input's value is a concatenated string, containing all the Options the user selected from a Dropdownlist. I update this input value with javascript, every time the user selects an option.

For that I'm implementing the **@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.propX)** helper, so when the user selects an option, I updated the **propX** value.

This works fine, even the values selected by the user are binded correctly in the ViewModel, and I can read this input's value on server side, the problem comes when this input is emtpy, **because the field is not validated** since it's defined as Required in the ViewModel I should get a validation message, saying that, but no, I don't get any message and my submit request is sent to the server.

Any ideas why this @Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.propX) input is not validated? How can I force this input's validation before sending the request to server.

Comment: validation on input fields is not enabled by default. [How to enable validation on hidden field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136342/perform-validation-on-hidden-fields)

Comment: It seems that my validation is enabled, because my form validates all my input fields except one, that's what I would like to know, why this input is not validated.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. You said your validation is not working only on hidden field, right? For hidden fields it not enabled by default not input. Check my link in previous comment, if it helps

Comment: that was very helpul, it's working now.